# What would be the equivalent to /dev/video0 in OSX Snow Leopard on a MacBook Pro (integrated iSight Camera)

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, live-streaming, ffserver, isight

I'm trying to do a live video stream of the webcam with ffserver and ffmpeg. I've found some resources on the net (#1 and #2), which more or less do the same thing.

I'm on a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.6.5. The webcam is an iSight integrated camera. If I look in /dev/ I can't find anything similar to /dev/video*, so where is the iSight camera mounted and how would I reference it in the ffmpeg command:

ffmpeg -r 15 -s 320x240 -f video4linux -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/webcam.ffm

Any ideas?

1. dmnet.bitacoras.com/archivos/software/streaming-de-una-webcam-con-ffmpeg.php
2. ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=665607

Comment: this question belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.stackexchange.com